# "Qué más" vs "ojalá": ¿tienen el mismo significado?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-entre-palabras

Me gustaría saber si tienen el mismo significado estas dos frases:

> **Ojalá** pudiese hablar bien español.
>
> **Qué más** pudiese hablar que un buen español.

Comment: No sé a qué dialecto te refieres. La única estructura que se me ocurre como similar a "Ojalá" en Argentina es "Qué más quisiera que (poder) hablar un buen español".

Comment: Estoy hablando del español estándar

Answer (score 1):

La oración:

- Qué más pudiese hablar que un buen español.

parece ser una forma algo poética, e inusual, de decir:

- Ojalá pudiera/pudiese hablar un buen español.

Una forma igualmente sofisticada pero más usual sería:

- Qué más quisiera (o quisiese) que (poder) hablar un buen español.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. Nótese que también usamos _más quisiera..._ para indicar deseo o burla (_más quisiera Ronaldo ser tan bueno como Messi_).

Comment: Es verdad. También se usa mucho en segunda persona: *Más quisieras estar en mi lugar* (= Qué más quisieras que estar en mi lugar.)

Answer (score 0):

El significado de [ojalá](https://dle.rae.es/?id=QxGRTE0) es el de desear fuertemente que algo suceda

> Del ár. hisp. law šá lláh 'si Dios quiere'.
>
> 1. interj. Denota vivo deseo de que suceda algo.

La construcción que citas, —aunque no esté gramaticalmente bien construida—, sí tiene el [sentido retórico](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TzZfwOK) de ***no anhelar nada más que*** algo.

> ¿Qué más [pedir / querer / desear / poder] que hablar bien la lengua española?
>
> **¡Nada!**

Por lo cual sí puede decirse que es una manera de significar un deseo vivo o intenso.